# How can I send a response in Ajax through php script

Tags: php, ajax

I need to send a response from the ajax to the php code. Alert msg as to be displayed when success.. I have to get  entered date should be displayed in the url and response as to  be sent..

```
  <script>  
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('#txtdate').change(function(){
    date = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({ 
                 type: 'GET',   
                 url: "http://localhost/data/check_date.php?date=" +date , 
                 success: function() {
                  alert(data);

                           }
           });


});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: try removing `?date=" +date" ,` with `?date=" +date ,` in url, simply you remove " after data

Comment: Done..But I cant see any response

Comment: Have you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `"` mentioned at the end of the url because `date` is variable to be passed through url.

**To overcome all mistakes change your whole code to**

```
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('#txtdate').change(function(){
    var date = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({ 
                 type: 'GET',   
                 url: "http://localhost/data/check_date.php?date=" +date, 
                 success: function(date) {
                  alert(date);
                         }
              });

        });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Done..But I cant get any reponse msg

Comment: Which msg do you want in the alert?

Comment: I want the date in the alert box

Comment: I changed the code as u said..But I dont get any alert msg or anything

Comment: Remember your ajax call triggers only when you change the `txtdate` do not refresh and check for the alert

Answer (score 0):

Two error:
**1:**

```
date = $(this).val();
```

to

```
var date = $(this).val();
```

**2:**

```
url: "http://localhost/data/check_date.php?date=" +date ",
```

to

```
url: "http://localhost/data/check_date.php?date=" +date ,
```

**3:**

```
success: function() {
```

to

```
success: function(data) {
```

All script:

```
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('#txtdate').change(function(){
    var date = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({ 
                 type: 'GET',   
                 url: "http://localhost/data/check_date.php?date=" +date , 
                 success: function(data) {
                  alert(data);

                           }
           });


});
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = $(this).val();
$.ajax({ 
   type: 'GET',   
   url: "http://localhost/data/check_date.php?date=" +date , 
   dataType: 'text',
   success: function(data) { //add data in the function which is returned from the file
    alert(data);
   }
});
```

also try opening your network tab by clicking `F12` in your browser before doing ajax request, if there's some error in your php file you can view it here in network tab, see if it helps